# Access SQL Enter Parameter Value when trying to export to excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I Am trying to run this SQL statement and then export the result to an excel spread sheet. I've looked through the the internet and found this, which seemed to work for other users.

It runs but asks me to "Enter Parameter Value" linking to "selecteduser" on line 4 of the code, the message box shows up at the point where the code starts here: DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet. If I click ok the excel sheet is created but with nothing in except the titles from the selected columns from the tables in the database. If i put valid data into the text box and press ok, then the excel spreadsheet is created with the correct data showing.

I know that the selected data in the ComboBox is been stored, because if I do a Message box it shows the selected data from the combobox.

Any ideas anyone? It's obvious the data isn't been passed through somewhere, but I can't see where.

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strQry As String
Dim selecteduser As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim Qdf As QueryDef

selecteduser = Me.Combo6.Column(0)

strSQL = "SELECT tblPra.praNo, tblFolder.folder, tblFolder.fullTitle FROM tblPra INNER JOIN (tblFolder INNER JOIN tblRelationship ON tblFolder.folderID = tblRelationship.folderID) ON tblPra.praID = tblRelationship.praID WHERE (((tblPra.praNo)=selecteduser));"
strQry = "tempuser"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set Qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(strQry, strSQL)

On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "strQry"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, _
strQry, "C:\Users\prc93\Desktop\test.xls", True

DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, strQry

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `selecteduser` in your query needs to be outside of the quotes. as it is a string it needs to be in single quotes like `'selecteduser'`. Now if you msgbox your query and you should see that the `selecteduser` equals your `column (0)`. are you sure that `selecteduser` needs to be a string and not a number e.g. `long`?

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strQry As String
Dim selecteduser As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim Qdf As QueryDef

selecteduser = Me.Combo6.Column(0)

strSQL = "SELECT tblPra.praNo, tblFolder.folder, tblFolder.fullTitle FROM " &_ 
         "tblPra INNER JOIN (tblFolder INNER JOIN tblRelationship ON " &_
         "tblFolder.folderID = tblRelationship.folderID) ON " &_
         "tblPra.praID = tblRelationship.praID " &_
         "WHERE (((tblPra.praNo)='" & selecteduser & "'));"
strQry = "tempuser"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set Qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(strQry, strSQL)

On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "strQry"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, _
strQry, "C:\Users\prc93\Desktop\test.xls", True

DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, strQry

End Sub
```

Comment: Yea its got both Letters and Numbers in, so it needs to be a string. But your changes with the '" & &"' worked! thank you very much :)

Comment: I was just checking because in many cases `column(0)` is given to the primary key and autonumber, so would be a number. glad I could help!